# Use of one class object in another class?

Tags: c#, class, object, collections

i am making applications in c#.In that application i have one class as `DataCapture.cs`. In same application i have another class as `Listner.cs` . Here in Listner.cs class i want to use object of `DataCapture.cs` without creating new object of `DataCapture.cs`. As if i am creating new object of `DataCapture.cs`,i cant access the the data `DataCapture.cs` as it creates the new instance of class and all data gets lost as i am using collection in `DataCapture.cs`.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Downvoter can you tell me whats the wrong with question?

Comment: I did not downvote, but I can see why people do it because your question is not clear. Code would have clarified a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You vould use the the `singleton pattern` to ensure that only `one object` of the `class` exists. You could then get the `object` as,

`DataCapture.Instance.` ...... where .Inastance is `public static`.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass a reference of already created DataCapture's object to the Listener class. For instance pass the instance to the Listener's constructor.

```
class Listener{
  Listener(DataCapture data)
  {
     this.data = data;
  }
}
```

Now within Listener you have access to DataCapture instance.

Answer (score 1):

if I clear understand what you'e asking for, you can do somethign like this.

```
//somewhere in the code you create 
DataCapture dataCapture = new DataCapture();
```

And, considering that Listener *needs* actually DataCapture

```
public class Listener {

  DataCapture _dataCapture = null; 

  public Listener(DataCapture dc) {
    _dataCapture = dc;
  }

  /* Use _dataCapture member inside listener class member functions. 
     One instance of DataCapture class, shared inside Listener.
  */
}
```

If this is not what you're asking for, please clatify your question.