# accessing form class object in a separate form C#

Tags: c#, .net, forms, class, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use of one class object in another class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572206/use-of-one-class-object-in-another-class)

This will be my first post because I can normally find my answer with a few web searches. I am mainly a C++ programmer but I am currently working on a program for a friend of mine in .NET/C#.

I have created a class that contains a few members and a list.

I declared my class in my main form. Now I need to access that class object in all my other forms that I have to create so that I can store and access all my saved information.

So my problem is that I do not know how I would go about making that object accessible in all created forms.

I am just not experienced enough with C# and .NET to really work this one out so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, but this really is one of the most frequently asked questions here. Tons of similar questions in the sidebar on the right.

Comment: try making it a public class, method, and variable

Comment: Are you working in visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

You'd do it the same way (basically) that you would in C++:  You can take the object to a scope that all forms can see it, or you can make the object `public` if you want to keep it in the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your object to the other forms by ref..

```
//constructor of main form
public Form1()
{
    MyClass foo = new MyClass();
    OtherForm form = new OtherForm(foo);
}

//overload the other forms constructor
public OtherForm(MyClass foo)
{

}
```